# If $A$ is a real skew-symmetric matrix, why is $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I proved the first part of this question: That $I-A$ and $I+A$ are nonsingular.

The second part of question asks about orthogonality. So, I tried to prove by assuming

that there exists transpose of that matrix and the product of the two matrices would be the identity.

Can anybody give me some thoughts on how to complete this line of reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is a real skew symmetric matrix, then $A^T = -A$. Now, let $B = (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$.

To show that $B$ is orthogonal, we need to compute $B^T$ in terms of $A$ and show that $B^TB = I$.

Do you see how to do this? You will need to use the fact that $I-A$ and $I+A$ commute.

Comment: I got transpose of B is equal to inverse of (I-A) times (I+A). Let me denote * inverse,  (I-A)*(I+A)(I-A)(I+A)*. This is what I got for transpose of B x B but can't see its identity

Comment: How do we know that I-A and I+A are commute?

Comment: Multiply out $(I-A)(I+A)$ and $(I+A)(I-A)$ and you'll get that they are equal. In general, for any polynomials $p$ and $q$, we have that $p(A)$ and $q(A)$ commute.

Comment: Thanks, not realizing that they are commute was why I couldn't do . Thanks for having enlightened me

Answer (score 1):

At first glimpse, this exercise seems without interest. Yet, think again ; this result, due to Cayley, is a very important one. Indeed, this isomorphism gives an algebraic parametrization of $SO(n)$ (beware, the $\det$ of the result is $1$). That is very useful in robotics or if you want to algebraically solve a problem concerning rotations.